# Macbook Pro Can't Boot From macOS Monterey of External SSD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, ssd, monterey

I have recently decide to install dual OS (macOS and Windows 10) on this newly bought SSD to run both Mac and Windows on my Macbook Pro 2017.

What I did was,

1. Disk Partition on Windows. Got three partitions where they are for **(a) NTFS Windows (b) exFAT for bootcamp (c) APFS for Mac**
2. Install and activate Win10 on **(a)**
3. Download and put bootcamp files in **(b)**
4. Install Monterey in **(c)** with my Macbook Pro, my system OS is Big Sur

After the installation, I tried restart with `option`+`R` but only **(a)** and my internal HD showed up. With Recovery mode, Disk Utilities and Startup Manager wasn't helping. I tried using System Preferences to directly set my start up disk, although **(c)** showed up, I could not assign it as my startup disks due to some error that pops up. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 partition tables when you have boot camp - one for windows and one for unix'y things (GPT?).. Windows knows nothing about the unix one, the one osx uses knows about the windows one (except it doesn't know about the boot crud windows uses (except at install time for bootcamp).  Would suggest to start with OSX first...

Comment: Hi Mr R, 
Thanks for the reply!
I am wondering what do you mean by start with OSX first? Does it mean that it's not possible for OSX to read both Windows and OSX on the same external drive? Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do that .. Is the drive formatted GUID partition format?  [not sure with apple silicon CPU, but certainly with intel CPU devices you needed it to be GUID format].